# Javascript filter function to filter out falsy values

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and have the following code to filter out falsy values from a string.

```
function isFalsy(value) {
  if(value === false) 
    return false;
  if(value === null)
   return false;
  if(value === 0)
   return false;
  if (value ==="")
   return false;
  if (value === undefined)
   return false;
  if(value.isNaN)
   return false;

  return true;

}
function bouncer(arr) {

  arr = arr.filter(isFalsy);
  return arr;
}
```

I run the following:

```
bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]);
```

I except the result to be:

```
[1,2]
```

but it gave me

```
[1,null, 2]
```

What is going on?

Comment: I don't think that's what it gave you, it's the `NaN` check, not the `null` check, that's incorrect. `if(value.isNaN)` checks for a property called `isNaN` on `value`. The correct check is `if (isNaN(value))`

Comment: And indeed: https://jsfiddle.net/03o1e7uw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't `null`, it's `NaN`; proof:

```js
function isFalsy(value) {
  if(value === false) 
    return false;
  if(value === null)
   return false;
  if(value === 0)
   return false;
  if (value ==="")
   return false;
  if (value === undefined)
   return false;
  if(value.isNaN)
   return false;

  return true;

}
function bouncer(arr) {

  arr = arr.filter(isFalsy);
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]));
```

The reason is that `if(value.isNaN)` checks to see if a property called `isNaN` on `value` is truthy. The correct check is `if (isNaN(value))`, because `isNaN` is a built-in function for testing for `NaN` (since `NaN === NaN` is `false` so you can't check that way):

```js
function isFalsy(value) {
  if(value === false) 
    return false;
  if(value === null)
   return false;
  if(value === 0)
   return false;
  if (value ==="")
   return false;
  if (value === undefined)
   return false;
  if(isNaN(value))
   return false;

  return true;

}
function bouncer(arr) {

  arr = arr.filter(isFalsy);
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]));
```

That said, returning any falsy value from the filter callback will remove the entry, so you don't need your `isFalsy` at all (other than for learning purposes):

```
  arr = arr.filter(function(value) { return value; });
```

```js
function bouncer(arr) {

  arr = arr.filter(function(value) { return value; });
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use this whole, complicated function with a lot of conditions.

Just use `.filter(v => v)`, which will remove every `falsy` value.

`v` is an argument for the `Array#filter` function. We are filtering every truthy value and passing it to the `res` variable. Falsy values - `[0, false, "", null, undefined, NaN]` won't be filtered (passed).

```js
var arr = [1, null, NaN, 2, undefined, '', 0],
    res = arr.filter(v => v);
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: As the OP is learning JavaScript, I think you can add a more detailled explanation of how and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Array#filter()`

```js
console.log(bouncer([1, null, NaN, 2, undefined]));

function bouncer(arr){
  return arr.filter(a=>a);
}
```

Comment: As the OP is learning JavaScript, I think you can add a more detailled explanation of how and why it works.